# What type of drill bits are these?

Tags: metals, wood, drilling

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPV6dRqB6f__N1eCcmn6QkOStLpVdc-U/view?usp=drivesdk

Here's an image for bits Head.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/HS8hFqLeWn8jecka7

In the image above (Google Images & Drive) a bunch of drill bits I found in my father's house.
How do I know what are they used for?
Wood, metal or multipurpose?
I did some research online but couldn't find answers for a lot of questions I have.
If you view the image above you can see that bit #7 and #8 have the same size but with different body shape. Why?
Can you drill both wood and metal using the same bit if it's multipurpose?
Does bits color has anything to tell about its type?
Please be easy on me, I'm trying to learn.

[image]

Comment: You can paste photos directly into the text box here. GDrive has access issues.

Comment: Colour just tells you what the drill is made of, not what it is for. It is also not obvious from the photo how 7 and 8 are different. What you really should have given us are photos of the tip from an angle that is neither head on nor directly from the side.  The other thing is the helix angle but they look to all be the same to me.

Comment: You can "drill wood" with just about anything (even an ordinary wire nail!) . The question is whether you will make a neat hole by *cutting* the wood, or a messy one by *tearing* it.

Comment: @alephzero Yeah a "multipurpose" drill is usually a metal twist drill. Like how a hacksaw is a "multi-purpose" saw but is actually designed for a very specific thing.

Comment: IMO they look like typical cheap HSS (high speed steel) drill bits from the sort of sets you can buy everywhere, but with several sizes missing from the original set. They will drill more or less anything except hardened metal or ceramic tiles etc. If you try to drill something and the drill is not "cutting" but just "rubbing", stop immediately, otherwise the friction will overheat the drill bit and the drill will become soft, blunt and useless.

Comment: ... A cheap set of 10 HSS bits from a local store might cost $5 or less. A *good* set that will last a lifetime might cost $250. You get what you pay for, as always.

Comment: Hold the drill vertically and take a photo. The same way a person inspecting the drill head would do in real life if it was in front of them. Especially 7 and 8 since you say those are different. We are talking *really* close up.

Comment: @DKNguyen https://photos.app.goo.gl/DktqAdFa2JAuYPPcA

Comment: @alephzero No, I don't think these bits are cheap. They are made in USSR Soviet union back in 1988. A part of many things I found after my father passed away.

Comment: @Alaaj99 Yeah those look like metal twist drills. It's hard to tell if they're good or not when you haven't used them or know nothing about them. I was asking for photos of the head hoping they were S-points which would tell you they were good.The very tip in an S-point is ground to just be a point, not a line like what you have. They are rare. I still can't see a difference between 7 and 8.

Comment: Drill bits, even the most common material, HSS, can last a long time if used correctly. But that is a skill that requires some knowledge and feel. It isn't much appreciated nowadays, other than by machinists. Most people just treat drill bits as disposable (even though they can, in reality, be re-sharpened many times). Check near the base of the bits, in case there's some kind of marking (a few letters or numbers), although there's no guarantee that there would be.

Comment: Also don't use on concrete. Or only use on concrete. There's no going back to other materials.

Comment: @Alaaj99 There is no way to guess the quality just looking at a picture (and of course no way to guess that they came from the USSR in the 1980s either). High quality bits may have some marks identifying the manufacturer somewhere on the shank, but if they were made in the USSR 40 years ago it might be hard to interpret the marks even if they exist.

Answer (score 2):

They look like standard twist bits in relatively good shape (good cutting ends). Very likely High Speed Steel ("HSS"), doesn't make a difference which HSS for a homeowner. Presume they were properly heat-treated as any test other than hardness would cost more than the value of the whole set. And for the homeowner it does not make much difference if the hardness is HRc (Rockwell hardness scale C) 62 or 65. They were intended for cutting ordinary steels, cold rolled and hot rolled, but will cut anything up to about hardness HRc 40. NO ceramics or masonry. Different manufacturers may use different spirals on the flutes ( 7/8 difference ) but no real difference.  Easily cut wood, plastic, aluminum, copper alloys, etc. Manufacturers of products like plastics where they cut many thousands of holes a day may get special design bits that clean the hole and break chips and have a clean breakout, but again, no interest to the homeowner. Color of gold is a VERY thin layer of titanium nitride. I think black is normal heat-treat oxide, silver flutes and point are cleaned by grinding after Heat Treatment. All-black could be a thin nitride layer (no titanium). I don't pay any attention to color when I use them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep them for personal reasons, their condition and quality doesn't matter.

If you actually want to use them, there are a few "warning flags". First, apparently they were not in any sort of packaging. Somebody who knew the value of good quality tools wouldn't keep them loose in a box or whatever.

Judging from the sizes and shank lengths, they are part of a set but with several bits missing. Murphy's law says that the first time you want to drill a hole, it will be one of the missing sizes.

The USSR used the metric system in the 1980s but there is no easy way to tell exactly what size the bits are, and whether they will be the correct match for modern screws, bolts, etc.  Measuring drill bit sizes (or the size of hole they drill) is not trivial even if you have a set of calipers - another reason why the lack of packaging is a warning flag. Bear in mind that modern drill bits are easy to buy in size increments of 0.1mm, and there is a *reason* why there are so many different sizes avaiable.

Finally, even if they were originally high quality, you can ruin any drill bit in 30 seconds if you use it incorrectly, and you have no idea how these have been used in the past.

Personally, if I was considering *using* these bits I would first try them on some scrap aluminum or brass. If they didn't cut it like butter I would throw them away. Blunt drills are more trouble than they are worth, and if you had the tools and knowledge to sharpen and re-harden them, you probably wouldn't be asking the question!

Note, I'm not "against old tools" as a matter of principle. I regularly use some hand tools that are more than 100 years old, but I know their history, I know *why* modern replacements of the same quality would be very expensive, and I know how to look after them so they will last another 100 years or more.